# Powershell: extracting a comma-separated list of IPs?

Tags: xml, excel, powershell, csv, nessus

I'm dealing with a .csv export from Nessus, where essentially I have a column of **Host IPs** and a column with **Plugin IDs**

My customer wants an output where, for example, Plugin X would be in a column, and then next to it would be a comma separated list of affected Host IPs, and then next to THAT would be a count of the affected Host IPs.

[Pic of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNfvM.png)

After importing the Nessus CSV with Powershell, I was able to *start* to get what I needed with this:

```
$allfiltered | select-object 'Host IP','Plugin ID' | Where-Object 'Plugin ID' -like "57041" | Format-Table -Property  'Plugin ID','Host IP'
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
57041     10.1.1.1
57041     10.1.1.2
57041     10.1.1.3
57041     10.1.1.4
57041     10.1.1.5
57041     10.1.1.6
57041     10.1.1.7
```

But as you can see, I have a long way to go to pull this into the output I need (see pic above).

I think I'm eventually going to need a for loop to get all the plugin values assessed, but I need to figure out how to essentially query for "Take all IPs that match plugin X and place them into a comma separated list" and go from there.

Can you help steer me in the right direction?

-B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done simply using the `Group-Object` CmdLet.

Something like this for instance would group all plugins together, then you could iterates the groups, join the ips together in a comma delimited string and do whatever you wish from there.

```
$Grouped = $List | group -Property PluginID | sort PluginID

Foreach ($Group in $Grouped) {
   $IpsDelimited = ($group.Group | Select -ExpandProperty IP | Sort) -join ','
   Write-Host "Plugin ID: $($Group.Name) " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
    Write-Host $IpsDelimited

}
```

Here is the sample list I used for this example.

```
# The list is for example purpose based on what you have. 
$List = @(
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57041 ';IP='10.1.1.1'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57041 ';IP='10.1.1.3'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57041 ';IP='10.1.1.4'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57042 ';IP='10.1.1.6'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57042 ';IP='10.1.1.7'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57043 ';IP='10.1.1.8'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57043 ';IP='10.1.1.9'}
    new-object psobject -Property @{'PluginID'='57044 ';IP='10.1.1.10'}
)
```

**Resulting output**

[image: Resulting output]

**For fun**

If you were to re-export it to a CSV file, you could use calculated properties to manipulate your output object directly and export it with the modified informations.

```
$Output = $Grouped |
Select  @{'N'='PluginID';E={$_.Name}},
        @{N='IPSDelimited';E={($_.Group | Select -ExpandProperty IP | Sort) -join ','}},
        @{N='My other field';E={$_.Group.OtherField}}

$Output | Export-Csv -Path 'MyPath' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Sage, thanks!  I'm trying out what you've got here, but just so I'm clear, the starting .CSV has these columns: Host IP, PluginID.  So I need to be able to run a script to look at each plugin, one by one, and give me a corresponding comma-separated list of affected IPs.  It seems like what you have above is for a specific pluginID but not "any" pluginID?

Comment: Ah sorry...let me tinker some more, I think I'm following what you've done here.

Comment: Ok so that seems to work - thanks!  But I'm wondering how I can export that back *out* into a .csv with columns like this: "Plugin ID", " IPSDelimited","Synopsis" (Synopsis is a field from the original .csv that's been assigned to $allfiltered variable).